# Why doesn't my Ember computed property get a second argument?

Tags: ember.js

I expected a second argument to be passed to my computed property method, but it's not. I need this so I can call a setter to save my model with new data. Instead of that behavior, it appears that my computed property is called again right before I save the model, and clobbering the new values - the setter is never called at all because I only get one argument. Computed property:

```
changeBananas: function(k, v) {

  var bananas = this.get('bananas'), bananaList = [];

  console.log('args: ');
  console.log(arguments);

  bananaList = bananas.map(function(b) {

    return { color: b.get('color') };

  });

  if (arguments.length > 1) {

    console.log('I never get called!');

    return bananaList;
  }

  return bananaList;

}.property('bananas.@each')
```

Full JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/razimaxu/2/edit

I tried propertyWillChange() and friends to try to stop observers, but it did not do anything. Is there another way to do this? My computed property is there to do some formatting of the items before displaying them in editable fields. I expected to be able to change said fields and save just like any other fields that are connected to regular model properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time it will receive both arguments is if you attempt to set the computed property, such as `this.set('changeBananas', [])`.

It doesn't get called with both arguments if it has noticed a dependent property has changed.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, is there a way to get it to do that? How can I determine the new values that have been set outside of the computed property function?

Comment: why don't you change your changeBananas to be an observer ? call it 'modifyBananas' and instead of your return(inside the arguments.length if and the last return), set the 'changeBananas' property to the bananaList value like this: this.set('changeBananas', bananaList)

Comment: That gets me "Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {" and "Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined."

Comment: Accepting the original answer, as it did correctly answer my question. My actual problem remains, however.